# Addresses in decimal,binary,octal and hexadecimal

Tags: combinatorics, number-systems

One of the first minicomputers, the PDP-8 had a word size of 12 bits. (Recall the word size of a computer refers to the number of bits used to encode addresses.) what was the last address in this computer's memory space in decimal, binary, octal and hexadecimal?

I am stuck at this question. How do we know the last addresses in all four of these. Anyone know?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Recall that the maximum number that can be stored in n bits is $2^n-1$

$$
\begin{align}
  &\text{Decimal:} &2^{12}-1  &\quad= 2^{12}-1 &= 4096_{10}-1\\
  &\text{Octal:}   &2^{3^4}-1 &\quad= 8^4-1    &= 10000_8-1\\
  &\text{Hexa:}    &2^{4^3}-1 &\quad= 16^3-1   &= 1000_{16}-1
\end{align}
$$

Comment: And since we both know that this is for CIS2030 assignment 2, if you really are still stuck check out page 554 of your textbook

Answer (score 0):

The first address is when no bits are triggered (i. e. basically $0$ in any base), and the last address is when every bit is triggered (i. e. $111111111111$ in binary, $FFF$ in hexa, etc.)

Comment: Are you 100% sure?so 11111111 in binary, FFFFFFFF in hex , 255 in decimal and 377 in octal? Have I got these right?

Comment: Yes, on a $n$-bits address space, you got $2^n$ adresses in the range $\{0, ...,  2^n-1\}$. However, your bases convertion are wrong.

Comment: What are bases conversion? And also can you correct them or tell me how I can correc those? Thanks

Comment: $FFF$ in hexa is not $255$ in decimal, and neither is it $377$ in octal (and base convertion is converting from a base to another)

Comment: Oh ok. But why is it only FFF just three I did 8 of them? I don't get why only three FFF? Please explain. If it is FFF then I get 4095 for decimal and 7777 for octal. Are those correct now along with binary 11111111?

Comment: I don't get your question, but your base convertion is right.

Comment: Ok great thanks! I was just asking why is It only FFF instead of FFFFFFFF because for binary we got 11111111? So shoud to it also be 32 bits in hexadecimal as well? That's what I was asking.

Comment: @user277388: where did you account for the fact that the word size is $12$ ?

Answer (score 0):

12 bits so 2^12 - 1

Decimal -> 4095

Hexadecimal -> FFF

Octal -> 777

Binary -> 111111111111

You can see in the BInary representation, all 12 bits are filled to the brim with 1s. Thus this would logically be the *last* address.